# How to reverse the direction of fillet in SolidWorks 3D?

Tags: solidworks

I am trying to round corners in my design for better stability as well as more 3D-Print friendly design but I am having big trouble trying to get the effect I want to achieve. See where I am am having problems. I would like the yellow curvature on the outside to give a nice solid support but it is going in the other direction. I tried everything I could do but could not reverse the direction.

[image]

The effect I am trying to get is this, which I made myself and obtained it following tutorial, but there is no I can fix my original problem. My question is, how to reverse the fillet direction, which technique do I apply so fill grows on the edges and no go inward as shown.

[image]

Comment: They are separate bodies or parts?

Comment: Anyway the answer is [here](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/41168)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not demonstrably a graphic design question. But rather how to operate a application meant for engineering design, for engineering or industrial design purpose. Which is not graphic design.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 separate solids the only way to round the corner is this:

[image]

That's because Solid1 (=grey) doesn't have any corner there.

If you have a single solid (=the pieces are united) the only direction to round the corner is this:

[image]

If the pieces must stay separate you can draw the 3rd piece (=green) or divide the single body version along planes after doing the rounding.

[image]

(sorry for using something simpler (=DesignSpark mechanical, freeware) than SolidWorks, but I believe the solids are generally based on same ideas in CAD programs)

**ADD:** Seemingly I was wrong. Programs behave radically differently. In a comment the questioner tells that after combining these

[image]

to a single solid (=move face to face and unite) he still got only the unwanted rounding. In DesignSpark Mechanical the only possibility is this (the surface colors stay):

[image]

The parts cannot be united if they do not intersect nor are moved face to face with "Up to face"-option

Comment: Thanks for then answer. In my case the pieces are united so I would expect it will be rendered correct. Also the second example, I used the same principle, made one plane then a protrusion and then applies fillet. I am not sure the direction of the design has anything to with it thought, but I will experiment with this aspect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was correctly pointed out by the above user, then I followed up and found that indeed the two bodies were not touching each other even though they appeared to be touching (and they *were* protrusions). But anyways got some extra help from another user. Here is how it was fixed, [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgxSjmtKMkc)